Cannot save 'user' document to Sanity.io
I am following a YouTube tutorial from JS Mastery:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1RHDhtbqo94&t=4053s
In the login page I am using google auth to get user info and save it to sanity,
everything works fine but the user is not saved in sanity.
P.S. There are some errors in the console but I guess they won't be a problem:
warnings.ts:7  You have configured Sanity client to use a token in the browser. This may cause unintentional security issues. See https://www.sanity.io/help/js-client-browser-token for more information and how to hide this warning.
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy policy would block the window.closed call.
// I already set the CORS to allow localhost in Sanity
// Connecting to the client
// src/sanityClient.js
import { createClient } from '@sanity/client';

const client = createClient({
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_SANITY_PROJECT_ID,
  dataset: 'production',
  apiVersion: '2024-07-25', 
  useCdn: true,
  token: process.env.REACT_APP_SANITY_TOKEN // Only on server side
});

export default client;

// User Query
export const userQuery =  (userId) => {
    const query = `*[_type == "user" && _id == '${userId}']`
    return query
}

// Login Page
import React from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import shareVideo from "../assets/share.mp4";
import { useGoogleLogin } from "@react-oauth/google";
import Logo from "../assets/logowhite.png";
import { FcGoogle } from "react-icons/fc";
import client from "../sanityClient";
const Login = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate()

  const login = useGoogleLogin({
    onSuccess: async (tokenResponse) => {
      console.log(tokenResponse);
      
      // Fetch user profile information
      const userProfile = await getUserProfile(tokenResponse.access_token);

      console.log(userProfile);
      localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(userProfile));
      
      const { id, name, picture } = userProfile;
      
      const doc = {
        _id: id,
        _type: "user",
        userName: name,
        image: picture,
      };
      
      // console.log(`Doc to be saved is ${doc}`);
      console.log(doc);
      await client.createIfNotExists(doc)
      
      // Navigate to home page after login
      navigate('/', {replace: true})
    },
  });

  const getUserProfile = async (accessToken) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo",
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
          },
        }
      );
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("Failed to fetch user profile information");
      }
      const data = await response.json();
      return data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching user profile information: ", error);
    }
  };

I think there's is some syntax error somewhere and/or some modules are deprecated.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
